# Extracting field tags and their content from xml using lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have an xml file — the contents of which are at the bottom of this post — that I want to parse. I want to be able to create csv outputs with data such as 'forum title'; 'title'; 'user'; '{all w's in the sentence}'.

I have this code:

```
from lxml import etree
xmL = 'huge-xml.xml'

# Parse the XML file in chunks at a time and output info at every step of the way

for event, elem in etree.iterparse(xmL, events=('start', 'end', 'start-ns', 'end-ns')):
    text = elem.text
    print event, elem, text
```

But this will not find all tagged content, only somehow the w's.

**The XML to be parsed:**

```
<corpus id="politics">
<forum id="14" title="something & something" url="https://www.at.net/1">
<thread id="108" title="a title" postcount="87" lastpost="2005-03-31 06:35" url="https://www.at.net/111/222">
<text datefrom="20020526" dateto="20020526" timefrom="230000" timeto="230059" id="1185" username="user123" userid="46" date="2002-03-22 23:00" url="https://www.at.net/111/333">
<sentence id="776550f8f2-7765cba9fe">
<w pos="NN" msd="NN.UTR.SIN.DEF.NOM" lemma="|gräns|" lex="|gräns..nn.1|" saldo="|gräns..1|" prefix="|grän..nn.1|" suffix="|s..nn.1|" ref="1" dephead="6" deprel="AA">Gränsen</w>
<w pos="PP" msd="PP" lemma="|mellan|" lex="|mellan..pp.1|" saldo="|mellan..1|" prefix="|" suffix="|" ref="2" dephead="4" deprel="DT">mellan</w>
<w pos="NN" msd="NN.UTR.SIN.IND.NOM" lemma="|lycka|" lex="|lycka..nn.2|lycka..nn.1|" saldo="|lycka..2|lycka..1|lycka..3|" prefix="|" suffix="|" ref="3" dephead="4" deprel="CJ">lycka</w>
<w pos="KN" msd="KN" lemma="|och|" lex="|och..kn.1|" saldo="|och..1|" prefix="|" suffix="|" ref="4" dephead="1" deprel="ET">och</w>
<w pos="NN" msd="NN.UTR.SIN.IND.NOM" lemma="|död|" lex="|död..nn.1|" saldo="|död..2|" prefix="|" suffix="|" ref="5" dephead="4" deprel="CJ">död</w>
<w pos="JJ" msd="JJ.POS.UTR.SIN.IND.NOM" lemma="|snäv|" lex="|snäv..av.1|" saldo="|snäv..1|" prefix="|" suffix="|" ref="6" dephead="" deprel="ROOT">snäv</w>
<w pos="MAD" msd="MAD" lemma="|" lex="|" saldo="|" prefix="|" suffix="|" ref="7" dephead="6" deprel="I?">?</w>
</sentence>
</text>
</thread>

... and so on ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code extracts the forum title, thread title, username, and text of the w's, and yields a list of these parameters for each sentence which is then written as a row into a CSV file.

```
import csv
from lxml import etree


def readXML(xml_file):
    forum, thread, user = [''] * 3
    ws = []

    for event, elem in etree.iterparse(xml_file, events=('start', 'end')):
        if elem.tag == 'forum' and event == 'start':
            forum = elem.attrib['title']
        if elem.tag == 'thread' and event == 'start':
            thread = elem.attrib['title']
        if elem.tag == 'text' and event == 'start':
            user = elem.attrib['username']
        if elem.tag == 'sentence':
            if event == 'start':
                ws.clear()
            else:
                yield [forum, thread, user] + ws
        if elem.tag == 'w' and event == 'start':
            ws.append(elem.text)


with open('huge-csv.csv', 'w') as fd:
    w = csv.writer(fd)
    w.writerows(readXML('huge-xml.xml'))
```

I've tested the code with the following input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<corpus id="politics">
    <forum id="14" title="something &amp; something" url="https://www.at.net/1">
        <thread id="108" title="a title" postcount="87" lastpost="2005-03-31 06:35" url="https://www.at.net/111/222">
            <text datefrom="20020526" dateto="20020526" timefrom="230000" timeto="230059" id="1185" username="user123" userid="46" date="2002-03-22 23:00" url="https://www.at.net/111/333">
                <sentence id="776550f8f2-7765cba9fe">
                    <w pos="NN" msd="NN.UTR.SIN.DEF.NOM" lemma="|gräns|" lex="|gräns..nn.1|" saldo="|gräns..1|" prefix="|grän..nn.1|" suffix="|s..nn.1|" ref="1" dephead="6" deprel="AA">Gränsen</w>
                    <w pos="PP" msd="PP" lemma="|mellan|" lex="|mellan..pp.1|" saldo="|mellan..1|" prefix="|" suffix="|" ref="2" dephead="4" deprel="DT">mellan</w>
                    <w pos="NN" msd="NN.UTR.SIN.IND.NOM" lemma="|lycka|" lex="|lycka..nn.2|lycka..nn.1|" saldo="|lycka..2|lycka..1|lycka..3|" prefix="|" suffix="|" ref="3" dephead="4" deprel="CJ">lycka</w>
                    <w pos="KN" msd="KN" lemma="|och|" lex="|och..kn.1|" saldo="|och..1|" prefix="|" suffix="|" ref="4" dephead="1" deprel="ET">och</w>
                    <w pos="NN" msd="NN.UTR.SIN.IND.NOM" lemma="|död|" lex="|död..nn.1|" saldo="|död..2|" prefix="|" suffix="|" ref="5" dephead="4" deprel="CJ">död</w>
                    <w pos="JJ" msd="JJ.POS.UTR.SIN.IND.NOM" lemma="|snäv|" lex="|snäv..av.1|" saldo="|snäv..1|" prefix="|" suffix="|" ref="6" dephead="" deprel="ROOT">snäv</w>
                    <w pos="MAD" msd="MAD" lemma="|" lex="|" saldo="|" prefix="|" suffix="|" ref="7" dephead="6" deprel="I?">?</w>
                </sentence>
            </text>
        </thread>
    </forum>
</corpus>
```

The resulting CSV file:

```
something & something,a title,user123,Gränsen,mellan,lycka,och,död,snäv,?
```

I'm not sure if you wanted to concatenate the w's? If so, replace `yield [forum, thread, user] + ws` with `yield [forum, thread, user, ' '.join(w)]`.